# Is there a connection between the Stephen King short story 1408 and the novel Dance Dance Dance by Haruki Murakami?

Tags: short-stories, novel, stephen-king, haruki-murakami

I recently read the novel Dance Dance Dance by Haruki Murakami which features a horror/fantasy element in the form of recurrent dream sequences involving an man who is half sheep and offers the protagonist of the story clues to unravelling a mystery. The story takes place in the Dolphin Hotel in Sapporo. I am curious to know if Stephen King was inspired by or pays homage to this novel with his short story 1408 which is set in a hotel called "The Dolphin Hotel" in New York. Dance Dance Dance was published in the late 1980's and translated into english in the mid 90's. As far as I am aware 1408 appeared in around 2000. Does anyone know if King deliberately references Murakami or is it simply a coincidence? Thank you.

Comment: I doubt it. Are you basing this solely on the hotels' names? As far as I remember there's nothing about a half sheep in 1408, so I assume you just mentioned that information as a non sequitur.

Comment: It's the combination of the name, the setting and supernatural events happening in that setting. If it simply coincidence... well these things happen but I am curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be no link between the two. According to [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/Is-Stephen-King%E2%80%99s-1408-hotel-real-and-where-is-it-if-it-is), the hotel in 1408 is based on the Hotel del Coronado in California. According to [this site](https://murakamipilgrimage.com/hokkaido-accommodation/), the hotel in Dance Dance Dance does not actually exist, although there are a few in the area that may be similar.
Disclaimer: I've not read either story.

Update: I did find a [blog post](https://gatheringbooks.org/2011/05/07/re-visiting-dolphin-hotel-with-murakamis-dance-dance-dance/) that claims:

> ...the hotel’s name is Hotel Dolphin. It’s supposedly a nod to
> Murakami’s work which King is supposedly a fan of.

but the site does not provide a source for that claim. A movie review [site](https://flickdirect.com/movie-review/37/1408/movie.ashx) also says:

> ...the Dolphin Hotel (stolen from Haruki Murakami's Dance Dance Dance
> and transported from Tokyo to New York)

but again, provides no source for the claim.

Comment: I think we can chalk this up to coincidence then! thanks!